# What is the derivative of $(d/dt)f(g(t))$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb R^n$ be differentiable. If $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, what is the derivative of $\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)f(g(t))$?

I don't quite know what this question is asking for so I literally just said, letting $z = g(t)$, we have

$$\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)f(g(t)) = d(f \circ g)(t) = df(z)dg(t) = \nabla f(z) \cdot dg(t)$$

Is there anything else to do? I feel like there's nothing to work with here?

Comment: By  Chain Rule direct:  $(d (f(g(t))/ d (g(t)) * g'(t)$

Comment: @Narasimham Would you add anything to what I said above? i.e. full marks for HW solution?

Comment: Assumed nothing to add further.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go for a consistency check. First, as $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, it should make sense that the total derivative $df$ should return a scalar. Likewise, with $g: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R^n}$, the derivative $g'(t)$ should be a vector. Now we just use some intuition based on the univariate chain rule. We should think about

$$ d(f \circ g)(t) = df(g(t)) \cdot  g'(t) \ dt $$

where the above should make sense if $df(g(t))$ is a vector, namely, the gradient of $f$. So it makes sense to write

$$df(g(t)) = ( \ldots, f_i(g(t), \ldots) $$

where $f_i (g(t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (g(t)).$ Combining the above we say

$$ d(f \circ g)(t) = \nabla f(g(t)) \cdot g'(t) \ dt $$

which is just a chain rule. Note here that $\cdot$ denotes the standard vector dot product. Thus your working was correct following with what would naturally make sense by carefully looking at the operations and objects involved.

Such expressions are helpful when evaluating line integrals.

When extending the usual rules to higher dimensions, it may help to start with a simple case and then think about what the objects should look like. For example, do we have ordinary multiplications, or are vector operations involved? Most of the time, going back to single-variable calculus will build on what should happen in several variables.

Comment: I don't see how what you wrote is any different from what I wrote except substituting $z = g(t)$

Comment: This was just a verification of what you did, but making note that the structures should make sense with regard to the operations.